# How to make svg height same as the height of the page?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

I have an svg

```html
<svg style="height: 100%" viewbox="0 0 100 25" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path fill="blue" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
 </svg>
```

I want the lower part of the svg to reach the bottom of the screen ? How can I do it ?
I want the lower portion of the svg to the end of the page (even if its long enough to scroll)

Answer (score 2):

```html
<svg style="min-height: 100vh"viewbox="0 0 100 25" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path fill="blue" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
 </svg>
```

I think you can do it with min-height set to 100vh.